# Pagina de template e htacess Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, wordpress-theme

Em Wordpress:

Em uma página de template:

Tenho um link: `<a href="http://localhost/wpcurso/exercicios-questoes/?id='.$row->id_exercicio.' " >' . $row->titulo . '</a>`

Que aponta para outra pagina de template: `<?php /* Template Name: exercicios-questoes */ ?>`

Como fazer a url amigavel desse link para a segunda página de template?

Meu htacess é o padrão do Worpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpcurso/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpcurso/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa solicitar um GET nas functions do seu tema e validar no banco se bate com essa id, o titulo você passa opcional pois não precisa passar, com PHP ira pegar o id da seguinte forma `$_GET('id');` se atribuir esse GET em uma variável você receberá o id que passou na URL, até ai é ok, depois faça uma consulta SQL com `WHERE id = '$id'` Como segue o exemplo de Where que eu dei e veja se retorna true ou false, caso retorne os dados do exercício/questão só fazer a listagem dele nessa página. Segue um exemplo prático disso:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_['id'])){
         $id = $_GET['id'];

         global $wpdb; //Chamando função de banco do Wordpress para fazer uma consulta

      // Fazendo uma consulta e atribuindo a uma variável distinta
      $var = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = '.$id);

      // Vendo o retorno da consulta  
      print_r($var);
      die;

}
```

Comment: Não estou usando function nesse exemplo. Já recebo o id de uma página para outra através de um get na pagina de template, recebo e listo certinho o que vem do banco, quero saber que regra no htacess crio para receber aquele link que coloquei.

Comment: a url da pergunta funciona, mas queria que essa http://localhost/wpcurso/exercicios-questoes/1 funcionasse.

Comment: Teste isso: RewriteRule . /wpcurso/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: com php e htacess conseguiria fazer normaemnte, mas parece que ser uma página dentro do worpress e usando Template Name: exercicios-questoes talvez tenha que fazer algo diferente, não sei.

Comment: tente fazer oque eu te mandei acima no htaccess

Comment: tô sem acesso agora, amanhã testarei, mas isso não vai interferir nas páginas nativas do wp? categorias, por exemplo?

Comment: Vai não, olha como você ta usando a rota do Wordpress se ta usando /nome acho que vai, precisar configurar para receber id, caso ele esteja dando erro.

Comment: por enquanto só id pra testar, depois vou inserir a string id-xxxxxx mas aí é tranquilo.

Comment: se colocou oque passei pro Htaccess já está certo..

Comment: estava tentendo algo tipo ^exercicios-questoes/([0-9]) exercicios-questoes/?id=1$

Comment: valeu cara, amanhã irei testar.

Comment: se usar como falei vai ficar exercicios-questoes?id=1

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94737/discussion-between-rod-and-lucas-antonio).

Comment: dá certo não, na verdade dá erro 500 se inserir essa regra no htacess.

Comment: Então moio kkk, faz um plugin pra isso e passa um shortcode junto a página que crio solicitando o ID na URL